# Missing android classes - AbstractWheelTextAdapter and WheelView

Tags: java, android, import

I have installed the Android SDK and then the plug-in for eclipse. That is okay, but now when I imported existing project it gives me two errors. The first one is:

```
//The import kankan cannot be resolved
import kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView;
```

The other problem is:

```
//The import kankan cannot be resolved
import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.AbstractWheelTextAdapter;
```

I guess the problem is that this kankan is missing, but how can I add it ? 
Maybe it is not installed.

Comment: well, those imports are not part of standard Android SDK. when you checkedout WheelView project, you should checkout the library project too. i think the name is 'wheel' or so..

Comment: I have found the solution to that. Here are the files that I needed:
    http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fwheel%2Fsrc%2Fkankan%2Fwheel%2Fwidget

Comment: In your downloaded folder, you will get two projects... wheel and wheel_demo. Make wheel project as library project and make another regular android project from wheel_demo. And add wheel project to wheel demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the missing files:

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fwheel%2Fsrc%2Fkankan%2Fwheel%2Fwidget

I downloaded them and added them to a package in my project. Then just fixed the imports to them. And it works.